# query post based on comparison

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, filters, query-posts, meta-query

Each post in my site can be rated as 'good' , 'ok' , 'bad'. The values are stored in custom fields. I now need to show top 10 posts with maximum 'good' and it should not display posts with greater 'ok' or 'bad' values.

I currently do this by the following code

```
<?php
$orig_post = $post;
global $post;
$args=array(
'post__not_in' => array(get_the_ID()),
'posts_per_page'=>10, // Number of related posts to display.
'meta_key'=>'good',
'orderby'=>'meta_value_num',
'caller_get_posts'=>1
);

$my_query = new wp_query( $args );

while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
$my_query->the_post();

//code for filtering posts based on max good 

$good_val = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'good',true);
$ok_val = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'ok',true);
$bad_val = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'bad',true);

$maxValue=max($good_val,$ok_val,$bad_val);


if ($maxValue == $good_val)
{the_title();}}

$post = $orig_post;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

The above code filters posts after it has been queried, which results in improper results at times. Is their anyway we can do the filtering (i.e comparing 3 values) in `wp_query` itself?

Comment: Can you rephrase what these 3 values do and what you're trying to do with them? It's not very clear, and confusing. Also, use `wp_reset_postdata` when using `WP_Query`. `wp_reset_query` is for use with `query_posts`

Comment: Also can you correct your codes indenting?

Comment: It might be better instead to have 1 `meta_value` to hold the overall rating (as an integer) than making 3 meta_values and calculating on the fly. I suppose that's an afterthought though.

Answer (score 0):

> Is their anyway we can do the filtering (i.e comparing 3 values) in
>   wp_query itself?

What you are asking is tricky in pure SQL, though it can be done. `WP_Query` cannot handle the logic natively, though. You would have to create one or more filters.

Doing this with the data structure you have right now is not ever going to be especially efficient though. The best answer has already been suggested in a comment-- change your data structure so that you are saving rating to a single key such as `my_gob_rating`. You can then retrieve your data with a `meta_query`. Like this:

```
$args=array(
  'post__not_in' => array(get_the_ID()),
  'posts_per_page' => 10, // Number of related posts to display.
  'meta_query' = array(
    array(
      'key' => 'my_gob_rating',
      'value' => 10, // whatever the cutoff is between 'ok' and 'good'
      'compare' => '>=',
    )
  ),
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
);
```

You can change the `compare` operator to `BETWEEN` to get your "ok" data, and to `<` to get your "bad" values, if needed.

Also...

> `ignore_sticky_posts` (boolean) - ignore sticky posts or not (available
>   with Version 3.1, **replaced `caller_get_posts` parameter**). Default value
>   is 0 - don't ignore sticky posts. Note: ignore/exclude sticky posts
>   being included at the beginning of posts returned, but the sticky post
>   will still be returned in the natural order of that list of posts
>   returned.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query